# reverse proxying to https apache

Tags: apache-2.2, https, mod-proxy

I'm trying to reverse proxy https from http virtual host but getting an internal server error.
Here is my config :

```
ProxyPass /access/signin https://mysecureserver.com 
ProxyPassReverse /access/signin https://mysecureserver.com
```

in the logs I get the following:

> [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL
>   /access/signin. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure
>   the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using
>   LoadModule.

I am loading mod_proxy_http, here is the configuration for that:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /opt/apache22/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /opt/apache22/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be ?

Comment: It makes no sense to run a reverse proxy in front of an SSL site. You have undermined SSLs ability to cache sessions properly / can't use keepalive / can't cache responses unless you terminate the SSL on the proxy and re-encrypt to the backend (which introduces a lot of latency). Also, while Apache webserver + mod_proxy works as a proxy, even a reverse proxy, it's not nearly as effective as other tools. In certain configurations it *may* give some DOS protection. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 4):

try loading mod_ssl.so module:

```
LoadModule ssl_module /some/path/mod_ssl.so
```

and then using:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate.pem
ProxyPass /access/signin https://mysecureserver.com 
ProxyPassReverse /access/signin https://mysecureserver.com
```

where /etc/apache2/certificate.pem is created from the output of

```
openssl s_client -connect mysecureserver.com:443 -showcerts
```